# Cannot Reference Pivot Table headers due to header formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table

I am writing a SUMPRODUCT function that references headers in a pivot table for my report on a separate sheet. The header that is giving me an issue is the year, i.e. 2020, 2021, etc. I have tried changing the format to number, text, and even general, but it is still not referencing.

My pivot table looks like this.

[image]

And the report that I am trying to create looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to write a SUMPRODUCT function that would reference the product name, year, and the month in cell A1 of the report, to get to the aggregated sales figures. However it appears that the "2020" and "2021" in the headers of my report and the pivot table are not of the same format, and therefore it is not referencing each other.

The only way I got it to work was to actually copy and paste the pivot table onto a separate sheet and just keep the values only (so erasing any formatting all together). But I would like to reference the pivot table directly for report. Any ideas on how I can overcome this problem?

Comment: Please add some screenshots to show the issue. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, added screenshot to explain issue better

Answer (score 1):

The easy way will be to create another PivotTable structured in the way you want your report:

[image]

However, if you don't want to do that, you can do this. First, ensure that you have the Generate GetPivotData option selected:

[image]

Now, type `=` in one of your report cells and click on one of the values in the pivot table. You will see a `GETPIVOTDATA` formula, like this:

[image]

Examine the structure of the formula and note that the parameters (in my example above) are:

1. The value field
2. The top-left cell of my pivot table
3. The name of the first pivot field (in this case, Product)
4. The item in the first pivot field (Product A)
5. The name of the 2nd field
6. The item of the 2nd field
7. The name of the 3rd field
8. The item of the 3rd field
9. The name of the 4th field
   10.the item of the 4th field

We can edit this formula to only return the information we need. So, for example, you want to return the sum of the year, by product, for a specific month.

The correct formula to return that number would be this:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Amount",$H$1,"Product",$H15,"Year",I$14,"Month",$H$12)
```

When I enter that at first, it returns `#REF!`.

[image]

This is because that particular aggregation is not visible in the pivot table. To put it another way, there are no column grand totals. If I add the column grand totals, the formula now returns the correct number:

[image]

Note that in the formula above, I have replaced the "the item of the Xth field" with cell references of the products and years in the report. Because I have used the $ correctly, I can just copy this formula to the other cells in the table.

[image]

If you are still having issues after using this method, you should try to convert the report header to the same format as that in the pivot table *inside* the formula. You may find that something like this works:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Amount",$H$1,"Product",$H15,"Year",TEXT(I$14,"YYYY"),"Month",$H$12)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. I tried the GETPIVOTDATA approach but seem to be getting the #REF! error despite my pivot table including the grand totals. I am wondering if its because my pivot table is actually connected to an OLAP cube..

Comment: My limited experience is that with PivotTables using a shared data model i can only use GETPIVOTDATA using explicit criteria eg "Year", "2020", not references to other cells, which is a technique I otherwise use a lot, especially referencing input cells where the user can make a choice. You may find you have to do the same, which is more tedious to create all your formulas but might just work. What happens if you type "=" and click a cell inside the PT and press enter? Do you get a working GETPIVOTDATA formula then?